Set custom accept headers in Firefox
I don't like *.webp images, mostly because Firefox keeps downloading them rather than just displaying them, but also when I do want to download the image, I intend to feed it to other software, which don't take *.webp images.
I could simply convert them, which is what I've been doing, but it is quite annoying having to do so.
Is there anything I can do to pretend to not understand *.webp images and thus (likely) trigger fallback to *.png?
As an example, Discord CDN seems to send files primarily in *.webp, even though it can send the original file formats (e.g., *.png, *.jpeg, or *.gif). And yet their services (e.g., uploading a custom profile picture, emotes, stickers, etc.) only take *.png or *.gif. Which causes hassles when someone sends me an image and I want to use it as my profile picture or a custom emote or sticker as I need to convert the file first, when Discord could've sent me the image in the original format.

Experiment: In Firefox, about:preferences#general, Content Type, change WebP Image to Always ask and/or in about:config, alter browser.download.viewableInternally.typeWasRegistered.webp

Possible duplicate: How to disable support for webp images in Firefox? - Super User
